# Extreme values of a function without calculus

Tags: real-analysis, maxima-minima

Given a function $f:[1,+\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=\frac{6x^2+x}{x^3+x^2+x+1}$
How do we determine whether the function has a maxima or a minima without using derivatives. It is easy to do it for quadratics since we can derive an inequality with $0$ on one side, however I am stuck when it comes to rational functions.

Comment: Usually, this "idea" of not using the most simple and adapted thing to do something is the "didactical" constraint of some teacher or other temporary force of the written universe. It contains the valuable information that this can be done (easily) with bare hands. In such situations one uses a raw plot and tries to see where are the absolute / relative minimal and/or maximal values, if any. In the given situation one has to observe that the function is $\ge 0$, has the value $7/4$ in $1$, and goes $\to 0$ for $x\to\infty$. So an absolute maximal value exists.  In $1$ there is a local min...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $f(1)=\frac74$ and that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$. So, take $M\in(1,+\infty)$ such that $f(x)<\frac74$ when $x>M$ and then the point $x_0$ of $[1,M]$ at which $f|_{[1,M]}$ attains its maximum is that point of $[1,\infty)$ at which $f$ attains its maximum.